# How to fix non existent field in Gatsby GraphQL?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, wordpress-rest-api

I use Wordpress, Gatsby + GraphQL and I want to build a blog. Unfortunately all blog posts needs to have all "features" for example **featured image**.

The problem is when I remove **all** posts. So my blog is now empty but gatsby build fails because it expects featured image to exists. The same problem is if I have posts but they **do not have** featured image. If I want to run gatsby successfully I need at least one post with featured image.

Example GraphQL query

```
{
allWordpressPost {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        content
        featured_media {
          source_url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error

```
GraphQLError: Cannot query field "featured_media" on type "wordpress__POST".
```

I'm worried because my only solution is to create a dummy post with all these things. What if I want to create a blog for my client and he deletes this dummy post? Is there a better way?

I don't have much experience with gatsby so I would be happy for suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: use fragments for `featured_media` - should be treated as optional

Comment: Could you show me example please?

Comment: it isn't hard to search/google for `'gatsby fragment'` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51839893/6124657

Comment: It doesn't work. Still the same error.

Comment: open an issue on github

Comment: "If I want to run gatsby successfully I need at least one post with featured image." I think this assumption is wrong and the error is rooted in something completely different. How did you add the `featured_media` field to the Gatsby GraphQL schema in the first place?

Comment: I did this inside WP dashboard - "Add new post -> Add title, text -> Click on Set Featured Image -> Upload -> Publish post"

Now I have access to Featured Image through GraphQL.

Comment: Same problem here running:   "gatsby-source-wordpress": "^3.1.58", Gatsby CLI version: 2.8.8, Gatsby version: 2.19.8. Any news?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue that I was able to work around, but without seeing more of your code this is just a guess. When you render the data in your Post template file you can do a "not null" check. It could look something like `{data.featured_media !== null ? (<img src={{ data.source_url}} /> ) : null }`

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted but this is a common way of getting around  not having any data coming from a headless WordPress CMS to Gatsby front end. And specifically the question asked. 

This way your client can have zero post without breaking the build process. And when they add new post your component will add them as expected. Leaving this as it will help others with this issue in spite of the down-vote.